# Where can I find statistics on download amount on OSX?

Tags: macos, data-transfer, statistics

I'd like to buy a mobile broadband service, but there's a limit in gigabyte per month I can download.

Before i buy, it would be great to know what i currently consume, bandwidth wise. Is this statisti available anywhere on a vanilla OS X system? Should I get an additional application?

Comment: Short of tethering your Mac to an iPhone or iOS device that measures this more easily, you might ask the carrier if you could borrow equipment and pay for a metered amount and see how long it takes to burn that first allocation. Then you could buy with confidence.

Comment: A search for `bandwidth` on the App Store shows as the the top result a free app called [Bandwidth+](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bandwidth+/id490461369?mt=12) that sounds like it'll do about what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*OSXDaily* had an article [on this very topic.](http://osxdaily.com/2011/02/02/monitor-bandwidth-mac/) It will answer your question.

Comment: please summarize the contents of your link so your answer remains valid even if the link expires.

Answer (score 1):

Activity Monitor will show your network usage for the current session, but this gets reset when you reboot. However, if you're just looking for a rough estimate of how much data you use before you get your mobile service, this may suffice. After you get your service, you will probably find that your carrier has a way of checking via a website.

Regarding bmike's answer, I believe he's talking about iOS.